# Camera control in Playn

Tags: playn

I have worked on camera controls in 3d graphics application in Opengl. But i have to say creating a camera in playn with a top view, with rotation and translation looks really hard to me with the concept of layers. It would be great if someone could show us a example!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to playn and had the same problem. I cam across this thread while searching for the answer. I assume you are looking for a 3D answer, I'm working in 2D. A 3D solution could be similar however I do not know how the layers work in 3d so I could be wrong. Anyway here's what I found.

The problem is that translations on the layers are done all at once. This means that any rotation is done arround the origin, so if you want to show a rotated view of a specific location you have to calculate what that location would be after the rotation and then set the layer's translation to the rotated location.

I added this to the pea demo in the showcase project to test it out.

```
private void setCameraLocation(Vec2 vec, float rot) {
vec = new Vec2(-vec.x/physUnitPerScreenUnit, -vec.y/physUnitPerScreenUnit);
Transform trany = new Transform();
trany.set(new Vec2((PlayN.graphics().width()/2f),(PlayN.graphics().height()/2f)), -rot);
vec = Transform.mul(trany, vec);
worldLayer.setRotation(-rot);
worldLayer.setTranslation(vec.x,vec.y);
}
```

Like I said probably not the answer your looking for but it may help someone else or at least point you in a direction.